# TS: arbitrary subset of object keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following `Table` interface:

```ts
interface Table<O extends object, F extends keyof O> {
  fields: F[];
  rows: Record<F, {}>[]
}
```

That is, for every element of `fields` there exists a property of that name inside every `row`.

This is all fine, problem is, `F` will be declared only at runtime, so I would like to set something like

```ts
F = Partial<keyof O>
```

meaning `rows` don't include every key of `O`, but at least those inside `fields` array.

But this is not working: Now `fields` is a subset of keys of `O`, but `rows` include every key of `O`.

So how do I achieve: *`F` = an arbitrary but unknown subset of keys of `O`*? Then only if `key` is inside `fields` I could deduce `[key]` being a property of `row`.

Comment: "`F` will be declared only at runtime" doesn't make much sense; type arguments don't exist at runtime.  And `Partial<keyof O>` is meaningless, since it's like saying "a value with only some of the properties of `string`, like it has `length` but not `toUpperCase`".  And `F extends keyof O` already means that `F` just has to be some of the keys of `O`, you don't need to make it any more "partial".  I'm very confused about what specifically you need here; Could you [edit] to clarify your question, possibly with a [mre] that demonstrates something your current interface definition is doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but does this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwEYBsIB4DyyEAHpCACYDOyA9hgFYQJgA0yAYkaRBdQBQBrCAE8aMZPgCUAbQC6APmQBvALAAoZJuQxgELFQBcHANzqtyKDQDulIwCUmNKOVztpIAK4BbDNFlslAF95OXVA9XVyJiw4KBQEGhBKMFoaI3RsPCVkOCMARjYMIwAmNgQjAGZkQLZpACI4OoVTNSA) help you?

Comment: What I mean is, that `rows` in practise and at runtime is acutally of the form `Partial<Record<F, {}>>`. But I do know that every element of `fields` will also exist as a key at any of my `rows`. How can I make typescript understand this?

Comment: It comes from the way `rows` are created: The properties of `row` come from a `fields` array. Then `rows` together with the initial `fields` array are returned, so by iterating over `fields` I can iterate over the properties of `rows`.  Any other key that is not in `fields` my not be a property of `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need

```
interface Table<O extends object, F extends keyof O> {
  fields: F[];
  // every F is present, everything else is optional
  rows: Pick<O, F> & Partial<O>
}
```